# What constitutes gross misconduct for teachers in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment, professional-ethics

I recently heard of a story where an employee at a primary school in England was put on paid suspension. The reason given for this suspension was that she attended a peaceful demonstration against hate.

In the letter which the employee received, she was told that attending this demonstration could qualify as *gross misconduct*. An investigation has now been launched with regards to whether this was indeed gross misconduct.

This suspension also means that she cannot collect her own children from the school premises as she has been told to stay clear of the premises and to not make contact with staff.

Is attending a peaceful protest outside of work hours considered gross misconduct in the UK?

Comment: You've just stated that an investigation has been launched to decide whether it is gross misconduct or not. What exactly do you expect of an answer from us?

Comment: Perhaps because I want to know know if it is gross misconduct or not from an objective stand point?

Comment: The fact that *an investigation by a governing body is necessary* means there **is not** an objective answer.

Comment: @Nij I don't think you understand. Of course there is an objective answer. Investigations are launched all the time when the verdict is as clear as daylight, but to follow procedure they must "investigate" the matter.

Comment: There doesn't necessarily have to be a precise "objective" definition of the term, so there may not be a straight yes-or-no answer to "is this gross misconduct".  Perhaps the question should be framed as "who decides whether any particular behavior constitutes gross misconduct?"  If the employee can challenge the decision in court, the ultimate answer might be "a judge".

Comment: @Nate perhaps, but judges generally decide upon the *grey* areas in law based on existing statutes, prior court decisions, and common sense. Perhaps an answer could look like, "This will eventually be up to a judge to evaluate, but in the prior case Smith v. Jones (1975), 'gross misconduct' for a teacher was defined as 'conduct so wanton or dangerous that the teacher's students, or other students attending the teacher's school, were subjected either to a life-threatening medical emergency or victimization with respect to a criminal offense punishable by more than one year in prison.' "